# When WiFi is connected, does Android use any mobile data?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data, android-11

If Android says it's connected to a WiFi network, does that mean it's not using any mobile data? Could it ever happen that somehow an apps insists on using mobile data despite having a WiFi connection? In other words, is the only way to guarantee not to be using mobile data is to disable it?

For context, I noticed Google Photos doesn't sync even though it is set to. If I disable "only sync over WiFi" then it works, even if I am connected to WiFi and have mobile data off. Is it necessary to turn off mobile data to make sure it's not used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could it ever happen that somehow an apps insists on using mobile data despite having a WiFi connection?

Yes, an app can do this.  There is an [API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45190348/208273) that allows an app to bind itself to a particular network, and it could deliberately select a cellular network.  This might make sense for, for instance, an app for managing your cell carrier account (though a lot of those are explicitly exempted from counting toward data plans).

Most apps, however, will not do this: it would generally be quite user-hostile to use up a user's data plan when they're connected to an unmetered Wi-Fi network.